# how to verified if a path starts with string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I tried pretty much all the methods to test if path like this `file:///c:/folder/texts/int.txt`
  or `file:///d:/folder/texts/int.txt`  starts with `d:/` or `a:/` or `c:/` somothings with string `:/` some one have an idea please I try to use for this

```
if(strpos($URL, "c:/")) $URL = $URL;
else $URL = "http://$URL";
```

but it test just if the url starts with `c:/` and i would like that test if it beginning with somothing like `"{a,b,c,.............,z}:/"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `preg_match` with `PHP`?

```
if (preg_match("#[a-z]:/#", $URL))
```

This, however, assumes that the drive can be anywhere in the string, and therefore that the path in it is a valid one. If you want it to specifically start with `file///drive:/`, then use this instead:

```
if (preg_match("#^file///[a-z]:/#", $URL))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) with this method you can check to see if a string matches a pattern, in the following code I check if the `string = [a-z]://` (case insensitive). If it doesn't = that then I append `c://` to the start of the string.

Change the url variable to what ever you want and run the code, it should pop-up with the url in the correct format.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VJ69J/)**

## JQuery

```
var url = "working";
var re = /\w:////.*/
var x = url.search(re);

if(x != 0){
    url = "c://"+url;
}
alert(url);
```